# Problem displaying messages in serial port /dev/ttyACM0

Tags: c, stm32, uart, nucleo

I can connect to /dev/ttyACM0 through kermit, putty and python serial but could not be able to display the messages on the terminal. I am building a project using stm32f091rc nucleo board.

```
Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0, speed 38400
 Escape character: Ctrl-\ (ASCII 28, FS): enabled
Type the escape character followed by C to get back,
or followed by ? to see other options
```

I can see that the port is displayed in /dev folder but I am not sure if I am really connected to the port.

```
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

    UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 38400;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONEBIT_SAMPLING_DISABLED;
    huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    HAL_UART_Init(&huart2);

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}
```

UART init functions parameters match with the configurations I have made through Putty and kermit.

About the program, I have a main function calling UART_Transmit function with the following codes.

```
void printWelcomeMessage(void) {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)WELCOME_MSG, strlen(WELCOME_MSG), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)MAIN_MENU, strlen(MAIN_MENU), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem after deleting the UART_HandleTypedef struct initialization line.